# How to merge date and time into one variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I want to have a date variable and a time variable as one variable like this `2012-05-02 07:30`

This code does the job, but I need to get a new combined variable into the data frame, and this code shows it only in the console
`as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

This code is supposed to combine time and date, but seemingly doesn't do that. In the column "Combined" only the date appears
`data$Combined = as.POSIXct(paste0(data$Date,data$Time))`

Here's the data

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17341, 18198, 17207, 17023, 
17508, 17406, 18157, 17931, 17936, 18344), class = "Date"), Time = c("08:40", 
"10:00", "22:10", "18:00", "08:00", "04:30", "20:00", "15:40", 
"11:00", "07:00")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete

Comment: Assign the value to the column. `data$dateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `ymd_hm` function from `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

df$Date_time <- ymd_hm(paste0(df$Date, df$Time))
```

```
   Date       Time  Date_time          
   <date>     <chr> <dttm>             
 1 2017-06-24 08:40 2017-06-24 08:40:00
 2 2019-10-29 10:00 2019-10-29 10:00:00
 3 2017-02-10 22:10 2017-02-10 22:10:00
 4 2016-08-10 18:00 2016-08-10 18:00:00
 5 2017-12-08 08:00 2017-12-08 08:00:00
 6 2017-08-28 04:30 2017-08-28 04:30:00
 7 2019-09-18 20:00 2019-09-18 20:00:00
 8 2019-02-04 15:40 2019-02-04 15:40:00
 9 2019-02-09 11:00 2019-02-09 11:00:00
10 2020-03-23 07:00 2020-03-23 07:00:00
```